# Utah State Teacher Sexual Conduct

Tags: united-states, law, utah

Recently Ms. Jarrel, a former Utah high school teacher, was found guilty of sexual relations with a student. The student was expelled from school and, as for the teacher, she was sentenced to 18 months probation and 100 hours community service with a $900 fine.

In Utah state law, as I'm not very good at reading the legal code of conduct and such, is what this teacher did illegal?

I have found a couple of sites, however, because I'm not proficient at reading laws, it would be appreciated if someone could interpret for me or tell me whether this is illegal in Utah.

Link 1: [http://le.utah.gov/~code/TITLE76/htm/76_05_041200.htm](http://le.utah.gov/%7Ecode/TITLE76/htm/76_05_041200.htm)

Link 2: http://le.utah.gov/code/TITLE76/htm/76_05b020100.htm

Comment: Is what illegal?

Comment: All states have age of consent laws. You cannot have sex with minors under that age. Many teachers have morality clauses in their contracts, or stipulate that you cannot have a sex with minor conviction and still be a teacher.  As **Avi** said, "Is what illegal?"

Comment: Sorry is sex with a minor legal in Utah, especially when you're a teacher?

Comment: Age of consent in Utah: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_consent_in_North_America#Utah

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 did she have sex with a minor? or was she over 18?

Comment: Surely this is a question for Law.SE?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Law.SE and is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jarrell was 23, and the student she had sex with was 17.

> Courtney Jarrell, 23, was initially facing five years in prison after her sexual relationship with the 17-year-old girl was uncovered at Utah's Riverton High School last year

http://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/teacher-escapes-jail-sexual-relationship-teen-article-1.1750176

According to Wikipedia, in Utah, it is legal for minors who are 17 to have sex with someone who is younger than 17+7 which is 24.

> Utah
>
> The age of consent in Utah is 18. However, it is legal for minors aged
>   16 and 17 to engage in sexual activity with partners less than 7 years
>   older, and between 7 and 10 years older if the partner reasonably
>   didn't know the minor's age.[88]

the page also contains some of the legal language if you wish to look at it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_consent_in_North_America

Since Jarrel was 23, which is only 6 years older than the student.  What she did wouldn't be illegal, at least based on their ages.

*That however does not account for the student-teacher relationship, and it's not unreasonable to expect that the distinction might make a difference under the law.